# pySerial freezing after reading 3 times

Tags: python, serial-port, pic, pyserial

We are programming a pic and we've diagnosed that if we send data to serial port while its trying to send data to us, the program will lock up (both our python code and hyperterminal will crash when tested). It worked in hyperterminal and inputting it slowly (>.5 seconds between strokes), and would crash when the keyboard was bashed. So what we did was introduce a time.sleep which is longer than .5 seconds, but it is still not working.

Here's our test code.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("COM1")
ser.baudrate=2400

while 1:
    for i in range(23):
        ser.write(0x41)       
        time.sleep(.5)
        print("ok")

    rec = ser.read()
    rec2 = ser.read()
    rec3 = ser.read()
    print(rec)
    print(rec2)
    print(rec3)

    for i in range(23):
        data = ser.read()
        print(data)
        print("ok")
    time.sleep(5)
```

our receive data function. We used to have the "ok" being sent everytime it recieved a char (which is how we know that it freezes after 3 iterations). We brought it outside of the loop to see if that was causing the problem and it was not the case. It is not sending the "ok" at all with this code.

```
unsigned char receiveData(unsigned char *rxData, int length){
  // 1. Flag bit, RCIF, will be set when reception is complete and an interrupt will be generated if enable bit, RCIE, was set.
 char send[3] = "ok";

 int index = 0;

 if(rxData==(void*)0 || rxInitialized==FALSE) return FAILURE;
 while(index<length){
  while(PIR1bits.RCIF==0);       
  rxData[index]= RCREG;
  Delay1KTCYx(5);
  index++;
 }
    configureTransmission();
    sendData(send,3);

  // 2. Read the RCSTA register to get the 9th bit (if enabled) and   determine if any error occurred during reception.
  // 3. Read the 8-bit received data by reading the RCREG register.
  // 4. If any error occurred, clear the error by clearing enable bit   CREN.
 return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Probably the most important question here is, is it a real comm port or a USB<->serial dongle? If it is a dongle, whats the make and model?

Comment: What PIC? Because if it's the PIC16F87XA or similar, that `receiveData` function is wrong — the `RCIF` flag is set when the receive buffer is full, and is cleared when `RCREG` is empty, ie. read.

Comment: Wait, I misread the code. I'll think some more.

Answer (score 2):

(This answer assumes that you are using a PIC16, suggested by the names of certain registers.)

In short, it looks like a buffer overflow coupled with a bug in that loop in `receiveData`. The fact that it's freezing after three characters are sent in short succession might be explained by p117 of the manual:

> It is possible for two bytes of data to be received and transferred to the RCREG FIFO and a third byte to begin shifting to the RSR register

This would explain the magic number three.

Stepping through your PIC code, consider the following scenario (just an example). First time around:

```
// One character already in RCREG - RCIF set
while(PIR1bits.RCIF==0);
// Reads ONE character - RCIF clear
rxData[index]= RCREG;
// While waiting here, two more characters are received - RCIF set
Delay1KTCYx(5);
index++;
```

Second time around:

```
// RCIF set from before
while(PIR1bits.RCIF==0);
// Reads ONE character - RCIF STILL set, ONE character remains in UART FIFO!
rxData[index]= RCREG;
// While waiting here, three more characters are received
// RCIF set, RCREG fills up and the third character is discarded!
Delay1KTCYx(5);
index++;
```

Now the rest of the loop will keep reading from RCREG until `index == length`, but since some characters were discarded while the UART FIFO was full, you'll never get there and appear to freeze!

What is even more likely is that you are receiving characters before you even get to that function, so the UART FIFO fills up before you even get there.

There are a few ways around this.

1. Do this in an interrupt so it's a bit faster to move the incoming characters into the buffer.
2. Use a loop for reading from `RCREG`: `while(RCIF) rxData[index]= RCREG;` this makes sure you empty the buffer when reading from the UART buffer, but it will not stop overflows outside of this function or during that delay though.
3. Check the `OERR` flag - if it is set, assume something bad happened and start over.
4. Have a stop character or start character (eg. end-of-line, punctuation, etc) that tells you when a valid command is starting or stopping. If you get two start characters without a stop character, or some other confusing combination, assume you're in a bad state and start over.

Some additional advice: you can go absolutely crazy trying to account and compensate for every missed character or problem like this in your PIC code, but ultimately it's just another comms error. Priorities in the PIC code should be: quick recovery from errors and not locking up. Error detection and sane recovery should be handled by the client code, where it's far, far easier.

Answer (score 1):

Does the communication from the PIC make use of the [RTS/CTS lines](http://www.aggsoft.com/rs232-pinout-cable/pinout-and-signal.htm) of the serial port ? Probably the PIC expects some sort of flow control and you are sending data too fast to it without any flow control. Read up on the limitations of the [PIC](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/en026583.pdf) and if needed open the port with [flow control](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html) enabled.